A novel written in computer code
When looking up strange novels of fiction some years ago, I heard of one that was written all in computer code, with if statements and some other bits of code that was used to tell the story of an AI.
But if I'm remembering it right, my guess at the right search terms aren't finding it?
Does such a novel exist? And what is it?
It's older than 2020, so it's neither:

Tomorrow and Tomorrow and Tomorrow
A Day in Code: An illustrated story written in the C programming language.


Hi @Malady ; I would usually say what detail can you add, but as you've never read the book I understand that might be more difficult that usual ...

It's not all written in computer code, but large chunks of "In the Key of Code" by Aimee Lucido are written in Java. As the novel progresses, and the protagonist learns more, the code gets more elaborate.

@ClaraDíazSanchez - Interesting, but no. I guess I'll toss in some more guesses, and mandate an adult protagonist. ... Btw, it's also known as "Emmy in the Key of Code"

The poem "The Computer Iterates the Great Trumps" by Gene Wolfe, winner of the Rhysling award for best sf/fantasy/horror poem of the year, is indeed in the form of a computer program.

@PeterShor - Cool! But what I'm thinking of would need more code, not just starting and ending. Also it's "Greater", not "great"?

@Malady: I think it's all computer code ...  the middle lines are setting up an array that contains all the descriptions of the greater trumps. But I agree that this doesn't  exactly seem like what you're looking for.
